# how to upload an image in GraphQL in flask

Tags: python, flask, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I want to upload picture while creating a task.
**Error::**
graphql.error.graphql_error.GraphQLError: 'Upload' scalar serialization is not supported.

graphene can't be used because ariadne and graphene need different version of graphql-core.

this is a flask-graphql webapp and i don't want to use any other api.

```
ariadne==0.17.0
flask-graphql==2.0.1
graphene_file_upload==1.3.0
graphql_core==3.2.0

i am new to graphql can somebody help me to upload a picture.

**routes.py**

type_defs = load_schema_from_path('./api/schema.graphql')
schema = make_executable_schema(type_defs, query, upload_scalar,mutation,snake_case_fallback_resolvers)

**schema.graphql**
 
scalar Upload

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}

type Todo {
    id: ID!
    title:String
    file:Upload
    description: String!
    
}
type TodoResult {
    success: Boolean!
    errors: [String]
    todo: Todo
}
type TodosResult {
    success: Boolean!
    errors: [String]
    todos: [Todo]
}
type deleteTodoResult {
    success: Boolean!
    errors: [String]
}

type Query {
    todo(todoId: ID!): TodoResult!
    todos: TodosResult!
}

type Mutation {
    createTodo(title: String,file: Upload! ,description: String!): TodoResult!
    deleteTodo(todoId: ID!): deleteTodoResult!
    markDone(todoId: ID!): TodoResult!

}

**mutations.py**

@convert_kwargs_to_snake_case
def resolve_create_todo(obj, info,title,file, description):
    try :
        print(description,"dtae")
        print("fue")
        file = {"file":(file,open("./static","rb"),'application-type')}

        print(type(file),"typeppr")
        todo = Todo(title=title,file=file,description=description)
        print(todo,"tofooo")
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit() 
        payload = {
            'success': True,
            'todo': todo.to_dict()
        }
    except ValueError:
        payload = {
            'success': False,
            'errors': [f'Incorrect date format provided. Date should be in the format of dd-mm-yyyy']
        }
    print("was hhh")

    return payload

**app.js**


function createTodo(title,file,description, callback) {
    
    fetch(`/graphql`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `mutation(${file}: Upload) {
                createTodo(   
                ,title: "${title}",file: "${file}",description: "${description}") {
                    success
                    errors
                    todo {
                        id
                        title
                        file
                        description
                        
                    }
                }
            }`,
        }),
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => callback(res.data))
        .catch(console.error)
}
**models.py**


class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Todo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    file = db.Column(db.String)

    description = db.Column(db.String)
    print(type(file),"fillle")
    #completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'file': self.file,

            'description': self.description,
            #'completed': self.completed,
        }
```